# Máscara de Campo de CPF

Tags: java, javafx

Como posso adicionar uma máscara simples de entrada?

Por exemplo quero quando eu digitar o CPF aparecer *111.111.111/11*, limitar a quantidade de caracteres eu já sei, apenas gostaria de saber adicionar esses pontos e barras ao longo da digitação do usuário.

Obs: Vi alguns exemplos aqui mas nenhum funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Não existe um jeito nativo de se aplicar máscaras em textFiled no JavaFX. Deve utilizar alguma biblioteca ou fazer o trabalho manualmente. Em diversas outras perguntas no stackoverflow você consegue identificar algumas formas de resolver esse problema:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732047/how-to-apply-mask-formatting-to-textfield
- Lib https://github.com/vas7n/VAMaskField

Comment: cara biblioteca muito boa, valeu, ainda nao conhecia. Porém eu queria que a mascara aparecesse somente quando começasse a digitar sobre o campo é possivel no JavaFx?